# Regular expression to remove Some HTML tags but keep Span tag

Tags: java, html, regex

Is there an expression which will get the value between two HTML tags?  Also if Span tag is there then I need to keep as it is

```
input
<table><tr>
<td>abc<td/> <span class="abc">Test</span>
</tr>
</table>

Output

abc <span class"abc"> Test</span>
```

I tried following solution but it remove  tag also

```
String input="<table><tr><td>abc<td/> <span>Test</span></tr></table>";
        String newValue = input.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
        System.out.println(newValue);
```

Output of above code

```
abc Test
```

but Output require

```
abc <span class"abc"> Test</span>
```

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: I tried for removing Html tag like-- input.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", ""); But I need to keep <Span> tag as it is. above code remove all html code

Comment: @Raje see, you need to provide that in your question. Otherwise we would think you haven't tried anything :)

Comment: No, you're not going to be able to do this reliably with a regular expression. You're going to need a parser. A regular expression might work if you're screen-scraping a specific, stable site, but even that is iffy.

Comment: @chrylis is correct. It's *impossible* to reliably parse any xml-like language with regular expressions because these languages allow recursive syntax. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead `(?!...)` that means *not followed by* to test the tag. Exemple in java syntax:

```
<(?!/?span\\b)[^>]*>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you are looking for:

```
str.replaceAll("<(?!\\/?span)[^>]+>", "")
```

This will look for a `<`, then look ahead to see if it contains `/span` or `span` before coming up to the next `>`... and replace all of that with nothing.

[Example](http://regexr.com?36vrt):

```
String str = "<table><tr><td>abc<td/> <span class=\"abc\">Test</span></tr></table>\";";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("<(?!\\/?span)[^>]+>", ""));
//prints: abc <span class="abc">Test</span>";
```